# Error 2115: Macro/function set to BeforeUpdate/ValidationRule is preventing {pgm} from saving data in the field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bound form with a subform.  When I make a change to the main form and then click on the subform, I get the following error:

> **The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property for this field is preventing {program name} from saving the data in the field.**
>
> - If this is a macro, open the macro in the Macro window and remove the action that forces a save (for example, GoToControl).
> - If the macro includes a SetValue action, set the macro to the AfterUpdate property of the control instead.
> - If this is a function, redefine the function in the Module window.

If I make a change on the main form, then click on the record selector box or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save, and then click on the subform I do not get the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was a call to `DoEvents` in the `Form_BeforeUpdate` procedure.  The simplest solution is to remove the call to `DoEvents`.

In my particular case, the call to `DoEvents` was buried deep down in the call stack, so be sure to follow all of your code paths or just do a global search on `DoEvents`.

---

To reproduce this error:

1. Create a new form
2. Specify a RecordSource for the form (i.e., make it a bound form)
3. Add a subform control (note: there is no need to assign a SourceObject to the subform control)
4. Set the Form BeforeUpdate property to `[Event Procedure]`
5. Add the following code to the form's code module:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
       DoEvents
   End Sub
   ```
6. Make a change to the data on the main form
7. Click directly on the subform control
8. Receive error message noted in the question

Comment: As bizarre as this sounds, I can confirm that this works. I was getting the exact same error, commented out the `DoEvents` commands being called in `Form_BeforeUpdate`, and that fixed my problem.

Comment: I can confirm this too. I have the same error and I track it down to a 'DoEvents' in a sub nested deep within what my code calls after the beforeUpdate event. What is stranger is that if I add a breakpoint and trace the issue step by the step, the error is not triggered.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :) Thanks a lot